# EXC_BAD_ACESS while accessing string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have defined  `@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *usrId;`
then assigned a value like this:

```
usrId=[Screen.Info valueForKey:@"id"];
```

Then in `dealloc` I am releasing the string `usrId`. This code is in a `viewController` which I am pushing to `navController`, then I'm popping it. But the next time I again push this `viewController`, an `EXC_BAD_ACESS` happens at the statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning your value as

```
self.usrId = [Screen.Info valueForKey:@"id"];
```

or

```
usrId = [[Screen.Info valueForKey:@"id"] retain];
```

By doing it as you do it you just assign the value of `usrId` to `[Screen.Info valueForKey:@"id"]` so when you release it in the dealloc you release whatever is stored in `[Screen.Info valueForKey:@"id"]` also. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Never** release an object if you didn't allocated or retained it. When you write:

```
NSString *usrId = [Screen.Info valueForKey:@"id"];
```

You are just giving a reference to it, neither allocating nor retaining it. So you can either, use one of the following, then release in the dealloc, or you shouldn't release it at all.

```
NSString *usrId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[Screen.Info valueForKey:@"id"]];

NSString *usrId =[[Screen.Info valueForKey:@"id"] retain];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `usrId` directly uses the iVar and not the property so it is not being retained properly. You need to use the [dot syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17), so change it to `self.usrId = [Screen.Info valueForKey:@"id"];` to use the property.